# Hidden Python memory leak

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory-leaks, jupyter-notebook

In the following code, the memory usage goes around 1G up between iteration c1=0 and iteration c1=60. Can you help me spot the leak?

```
# M = 1000, N=18000
# data is a pandas dataframe with N rows and M columns (it is already loaded when this code begins).

mymat = np.zeros((M,M,N), dtype=bool)    
table = pd.Series(index=data.index, data=np.array(range(N))) 
data_std = data.std(axis=1)

for c1 in range(M):
    for c2 in range(M):
        if c1!=c2:
            mymat[c1,c2,list(
                table.loc[data.index[data.iloc[:,c1]-data.iloc[:,c2]>data_std]])] = True
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code or at least a description of what it actually does.

Comment: I added a description of the code

Comment: Well, if memory use keeps steadily increasing, you're leaking some memory somewhere (i.e. keeping copies of variables around or such).

Comment: @AKX Can you help?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. I'll take a look, but yeah, this looks like a memory leak somewhere down the line...

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually seem to be a memory leak at all but an optimization NumPy or your OS gives you. (Likely your OS, considering there were OS-specific differences in how your code worked in the original question.)

Here's a simplified `example.py` – the basic idea is the same.

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import psutil

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

def print_memory(message):
    rss = process.memory_info().rss
    print(f"{message:30s} {rss // 1024:7d}kb")

M = N = 1000

print_memory('start')
#mymat = np.zeros((M, M, N), dtype=bool)
#mymat = (np.random.random((M, M, N)) > 0.5)
print_memory('generated')
for c1 in range(M):
    if c1 % 100 == 0:
        print_memory(f'iteration {c1}')
    for c2 in range(M):
        mymat[c1, c2, [1, 2, 3]] = True
print_memory(f'end')
print(mymat.nbytes, mymat.dtype, mymat.shape)
```

Running this with the first `mymat` line enabled (i.e. generating zeros) prints out

```
$ python3 example.py
start                            23552kb
generated                        23564kb
iteration 0                      23564kb
iteration 100                   121340kb
iteration 200                   218996kb
iteration 300                   316652kb
iteration 400                   414320kb
iteration 500                   511976kb
iteration 600                   609632kb
iteration 700                   707288kb
iteration 800                   804944kb
iteration 900                   902600kb
end                            1000256kb
1000000000 bool (1000, 1000, 1000)
```

so you can see that "generating" the 1000 x 1000 x 1000 array doesn't actually take up the 1 gigabyte of memory Numpy's `nbytes` says it does, but as it starts to fill up with non-zero data, allocations occur.

Running it with the second option, generating random data, yields this:

```
$ python3 example.py
start                            23404kb
generated                      1000004kb
iteration 0                    1000004kb
iteration 100                  1000140kb
iteration 200                  1000148kb
iteration 300                  1000164kb
iteration 400                  1000164kb
iteration 500                  1000164kb
iteration 600                  1000164kb
iteration 700                  1000164kb
iteration 800                  1000164kb
iteration 900                  1000164kb
end                            1000164kb
1000000000 bool (1000, 1000, 1000)
```

As you can see, all of the memory is allocated immediately, and what little memory increase occurs during the loop is practically a rounding error and likely just due to regular GC allocations. (`np.ones()` has this same behavior.)

As for your original 1000 * 1000 * 18000 array, should you actually need to fill all of the array, you'll end up needing

```
>>> np.zeros((1000, 1000, 18000), dtype=bool).nbytes
18000000000
```

18 gigabytes of memory. (This also points at the fact that Numpy has no specific packed data type for boolean arrays; each boolean takes up a byte, not just one bit. This is likely due to performance reasons.)